# Split and return all but first element in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I have a Column which is a **Varchar** like `a:b:c:d` or `h:i:j`

Here I want resultant column as `b:c:d` or `i:j` respectively

I tried `SPLIT_PART('a:b:c:d',':',2)` function but this returns only **'b'**

Answer (score 1):

Although you could do this with array methods, it might be simple enough to do:

```
select substr(str, position(':' in str) + 1)
```