# Presto substr operations: Split and return the first 3 element

Tags: sql, substring, presto

I have one column ip(which is string) which looks like this

```
a.b.c.d
```

I would like to substrate the first 3 elements(after being split by '.') of this ip and the result should be:

```
a.b.c
```

I tried to use the method in this post:[Split and return all but first element in Presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120746/split-and-return-all-but-first-element-in-presto), but found out that position('.' in ip) only returns the first element that meets the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Split the ip into an array with `split`
- Take the last item off the array with `trim_array`
- Put it back together again with `array_join`

```sql
array_join(trim_array(split(col, '.'), 1), '.')
```

See [Array Functions and Operators](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html) and [String Functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#split)

---

Using pure string functions, we can use your linked answer by reversing everything and then un-reversing:

```
reverse(substr(reverse(col), position('.' in reverse(col)) + 1))
```